# Installed mitmproxy OSX but cannot locate .mitproxy directory

Tags: python, ios, macos, pip, mitmproxy

I was able to successfully install mitproxy (confirmed by doing a 'pip list') but when I try to install the mitmproxy certificate authority in the IOS simulator using the command:

```
./iosCertTrustManager.py -a ~/.mitmproxy/mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem
```

I get an no such file or directory error for .mitmproxy/mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem. I tried to just find the directory by doing

```
cd ~/.mitmproxy/mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem
```

and even

```
cd ~/.mitmproxy
```

but again I get no such file or directory.

It's possible I am making a very simple mistake (I am a bit of a newbie) but I don't understand why I can't find the directory if the installation was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I move my `~/.mitmproxy` directory out of the way, then run `mitmproxy` at the command line and quit it, the directory is created with default files. So, you can create it by running `mitmproxy` and exiting right away.

Comment: Yes, I see this in the documentation now... I am very unfamiliar with the commandline, can you tell me the command to run mitmproxy?

Comment: The command to run mitmproxy is `mitmproxy`. If it is not in your `PATH`, then you'll have to give the full path to it. Typically, pip would install it as `/usr/local/bin/mitmproxy` but I don't use OS X so I don't know whether it would be somewhere else on your system. To exit you'll have to hit the `q` key and answer yes at the prompt.